# If a checkbox is checked use Jquery to change CSS attribute?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

Is it possible that when a checkbox is checked in a form that jquery syntax below or something similar can modify CSS?

So for example if checkbox field ("MoreThanOne") is checked then

```
jQuery('div.ms-acal-item[title*="VAC"]').css('font-size', '14pt');
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Be more specific... what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: in new/edit form or display form? on load or on click event?

Answer (score 0):

First you should handle the checkbox `onchange` event. You can attach event by using appropriate jQuery selector. For example if the check boxes have a common style then you can do as

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        //do the css trick 
    }
});
```

You can add the above piece of code in dom ready event of SharePoint page as below. This should go inside a Script Editor web part.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readyFunction);

function readyFunction() {

}
```